# What's wrong with nested git repos?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, git-submodules

I am in a situation where I cannot use submodules (or subtrees, I believe), and I can only use vanilla nested repos (the reason is somewhat unusual, but it has to do with building inside a docker container).

In general, what are the issues with nesting vanilla git repos in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested Git repo has no problem, except its parent repo will see it as a gitlink (a special entry in its index, representing a SHA1)

The problem is: that SHA1 reference has no URL reference, so cloning again the parent repo will lead to an empty folder, because the parent repo does not know *where* to search for the nested Git repo.
This differ from a submodule, which records the gitlink (same as a nested repo) *and* the URL of the nested repo (in a special file: `.gitmodules`)

If your parent repo ignore (in a `.gitignore`) the nested repo enntry, then both can co-exist without issue.